# use timer to close server as well as connection

Tags: c++, c, sockets, bluetooth

**Issues:**
1) To close down  the server say after 10 sec if request to accept connection has not come from client.

2) Also broke the connection and close the server if no packets has been received from the client say for 10 secs .

**Overview :** I have an application which opens RFcomm server connection  and DUT( Device under test) connects to it. Once connection with Rfcomm has been  established then the application  creates SCO server and listen for sco connection. All I wanted is to close the server if no request for conncection has been received on RFcomm or SCO side . Also close the connection and server if DUT has failed to send any packets with 10 secs.

As pointed out by forum member to me to use KEEPALIVE  but my application crashes as I think KEEPALIVE does not work with SOL_SCO.

Below are the sample code

```
int ScoServerListen(void( *handler )( int sco_listen_sock ) )
{
    printf(" start sco_listen connection\n" );
    struct sockaddr_sco addr;
    struct sco_conninfo conn;
    socklen_t optlen;
    int sco_listen_sock, sco_accept_sock;
    char ba[18];
    int *new_sock;

    // Create socket //
    sco_listen_sock = socket( PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_SCO );
    if( sco_listen_sock < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Can't create socket: %s (%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit(1);
    }
    printf(" start sco_listen connection .. socket created....  yeeee \n" );
    // Bind to local address //
    memset( &addr, 0, sizeof( addr ) );
    addr.sco_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    bacpy( &addr.sco_bdaddr, &bdaddr );

    if( bind( sco_listen_sock, ( struct sockaddr * ) &addr, sizeof( addr ) ) < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't bind socket: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno );
        goto error;
    }
    printf(" start sco_listen connection .. bind done....  yeeee \n" );
    // Listen for connections //
    if( listen( sco_listen_sock, no_of_connect_listen ) )
    {
        printf("Can not listen on the socket: %s (%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        goto error;
    }
    std::cout << "Waiting for connection ...\n";

    while( 1 )
    {
        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        optlen = sizeof(addr);
        sco_accept_sock = accept( sco_listen_sock, ( struct sockaddr * ) &addr, &optlen );
        if( sco_accept_sock < 0 )
        {
            printf("Accept for SCO failed: %s (%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
            goto error;
        }

        //using socketoption 
        //Get connection information //
        memset( &conn, 0, sizeof( conn ) );
        optlen = sizeof( conn );

        if( getsockopt( sco_accept_sock, SOL_SCO, SCO_CONNINFO, &conn, &optlen ) < 0)
        {
            printf( "Can't get SCO connection information: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
            close( sco_accept_sock );
            goto error;
        }

        ba2str( &addr.sco_bdaddr, ba );
        printf( "Connect from %s [handle %d, class 0x%02x%02x%02x]",ba, conn.hci_handle, conn.dev_class[2], conn.dev_class[1], conn.dev_class[0]);
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = (int*)malloc(1);
        *new_sock = sco_accept_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void*)new_sock )< 0 )
        {
            perror(" could not create thread");
            return 1;

        }
        ( void )pthread_join( sniffer_thread, NULL );
        puts (" handler assigned");
        close( sco_accept_sock );
        close( sco_listen_sock );

        printf( "Disconnect");
        //close( sco_listen_sock );
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;

error:
    close( sco_listen_sock );
    exit( 1 );
}


void *connection_handler( void *socket_desc)
    {
      // get socket descriptor
     int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;

     int read_size;

     char*message, message_client[ 200 ];

      //receive messgae from client
     while( read_size = recv( sock, message_client, 200, 0 ) > 0 )
     {
       printf(" very good\n");
     }
     if( read_size == 0 )
     {
      printf("clinet disconnected \n");
      fflush( stdout);
     }
     else if( read_size == -1 )
     {
      printf("received failed \n");
      perror( " recv fialed");
     }
     free( socket_desc );
     int rel = 200;
     pthread_exit(&rel);
     return 0;

    }

int RfcommListen( uint8_t channel )
{
    printf(" rfcomm --> we are at that start\n");
    int rfcomm_sock;                        // socket descriptor for local listener
    int rfcomm_client;                      // socket descriptor for remote client
    socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_rc);

    struct sockaddr_rc remote;      // local rfcomm socket address
    struct sockaddr_rc local;       // remote rfcomm socket address
    char pszremote[20]={ 0 };

    // initialize a bluetooth socket
    rfcomm_sock = socket( PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM );
    if( rfcomm_sock < 0 )
    {
        printf( "RFComm socket Error \n" );
        return  BtSocketError;
    }

    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
    local.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    local.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY_INITIALIZER;
    local.rc_channel = channel;

    // bind the socket to a bluetooth device
    if( bind( rfcomm_sock, ( struct sockaddr * )&local, sizeof( local ) ) < 0 )
    {
        close( rfcomm_sock );
        return  BtSocketError;
    }

    printf(" rfcomm --> bind successful\n");

    // set the listening queue length
    if( listen( rfcomm_sock, 1 ) < 0 )
    {
        printf(" we are in SCO Configure where listen failed  \n");
        return  BtSocketError;
    }

    printf("accepting connections on channel: %d\n", channel);

    // accept incoming connections; this is a blocking call
    rfcomm_client = accept( rfcomm_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &len );

    ba2str( &remote.rc_bdaddr, pszremote );

    printf("received connection from: %s\n", pszremote);
    // turn off blocking
    if ( fcntl( rfcomm_client, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK ) < 0 )
    {
        printf("Failed non blocking\n");
        return  BtSocketError;
    }
    // return the client socket descriptor
    return rfcomm_client;
}
```

Comment: Do a search for non-blocking sockets, that should give you a starting point for further research.

Comment: `new_sock = (int*)malloc(1);` -> `new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));`